# Binding to ldap server with "ldaps"

Tags: c++, c, ldap

I am writing a program that will connect to LDAP server running on port 10389. I am able to successfully bind to the server with the user dn and password.

Here’s my sample program:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "winldap.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
    ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    ULONG connectSuccess = 0;
    INT returnCode = 0;

    pLdapConnection = ldap_init("localhost", 10389);

    if (pLdapConnection == NULL)
    {
        printf( "ldap_init failed");
        goto error_exit;
    }
    else
        printf("ldap_init succeeded \n");

    //  Set the version to 3.0 (default is 2.0).
    returnCode = ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection,
                                 LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                                 (void*)&version);

    if(returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("SetOption Error:%0X\n", returnCode);
        goto error_exit;
    }

    // Connect to the server.
    connectSuccess = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

    if(connectSuccess == LDAP_SUCCESS)
        printf("ldap_connect succeeded \n");
    else
    {
        printf("ldap_connect failed with 0x%x.\n",connectSuccess);
        goto error_exit;
    }

    printf("Binding ...\n");

    returnCode = ldap_bind_s(pLdapConnection, "dc=mojo,dc=com", "mojo", LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE);

    if (returnCode == LDAP_SUCCESS)
        printf("The bind was successful");
    else{
        printf("ldap_bind_s failed with 0x%x.\n",returnCode);
        goto error_exit;
    }

    //  Cleanup and exit.
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return 0;

    //  On error cleanup and exit.
    error_exit:
        ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
        return -1;
}
```

How do I connect via "`ldaps://`"? ldaps server is listening on port 10636.

[image]

What is needed for my program to connect to “ldaps” on port 10636?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAPS is a protocol used to connect to ldap over an SSL tunnel. This means you'll have to start an SSL session (or TLS depending on the ldap version), and then use your  ldap protocol to connect to the server.

Here's the windows LDAPS protocol: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938703